# Replace in a string a series of numbers (id card) PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to replace the first 5 digits or the last 4 of the id card, it always comes before a "-" and a space

**String:**

```
$string1 = "** GALLARDO SERGIO - 74276932M";
$string2 = "** MONTOLIA ANTONIO - 74736619E";
```

I have two options to show the result, the first 5 numbers of the id card or the last 4

```
$result1= "** GALLARDO SERGIO - *****932M";
$result2= "** MONTOLIA ANTONIO - 74736****";
```

for the second option I have used a substr () but it does not work if a string comes with another type of text

```
$result= substr($string1, 0, -4) . "****";
```

thanks

Comment: This is not clear: so what are the rules then? I doubt `preg_replace('~^(.*-\h+)\d{5}~', '$1*****', $text);` is what you need, although "it seems to work".

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very helpful, I need to learn regex, I solved it by making a concatenation of functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage

```php
preg_replace('~^(.*-\h+)\d{5}~', '$1*****', $text);
```

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*-\h+)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars as many as possible, up to the rightmost `-` and one or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\d{5}` - five digits.

In the replacement pattern, `$1` refers to the value of Group 1.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o2yWqp/1).